# Setting My Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

On excel can I set the columns, cells, font size and font type, so that ever time I open a new excel document it will be formatted the same way?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by setting the columns and cells?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a custom Excel template file with all the modification and set Excel to load it at at start/as new file.
https://exceljet.net/blog/how-to-set-a-default-template-in-excel

---

1. Open a new blank workbook and customize the options as you like
2. Save the workbook as an Excel template with the name "book" (Excel will add .xltx)
3. Move the template to the startup folder used by Excel (XLSTART
   Folder)
4. Restart Excel

Comment: Please include core information from your reference. Link only answers are not preferred.

Answer (score -1):

*The most easiest method I would like to suggest you is,*

1. Click **File** Command.
2. On the Menu find **Option** at last, Click it.
3. From the **General Tab** find, **When Creating New Workbook**.
4. Set **Font**, **Size** and others as required.
5. Finish with **OK**
6. Restart the Excel.

**N.B.** This process will set default Font & Size applicable to Workbooks.

*Check the Screen Shot below:*

[image]

Comment: Write your concern that,, why this has been down voted?